# Assigning regions to countries in python with help of Pandas (or maybe other modules)

Tags: python

May I know if there is a way to assign countries in my dataframe to create another column "Regions" (like Asia, America, Europe,etc)? I found someone using geopy to get the wanted info like the regions, but is it possible to do without geopy?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom website parser to extract data from a website of choice, or google for existing downloadable tables with such data like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjatq6gv4brAhUFrosKHeKQDHgQFjALegQIBBAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.statvision.com%2Fwebinars%2FCountries%2520of%2520the%2520world.xls&usg=AOvVaw2MwR5nAZwXVOVb2mQ0ygc3) for example, and then load it into pandas dataframe.